# Wrong project or wrong attitude?

Tags: career-switch

I'm a middle java developer. Current situation at work frustrates me, but I can't understand if I'm too demanding (or lazy?), or conditions are really bad, so I'd be very grateful for an unbiased opinion.

3 months ago I left a nice project where I worked for 2 years, going for better salary to a large bank.
New project had some specifics I could not accept (they were not discussed before employment) and after two weeks I left that place. This is important because switching often is undesired.

Now I am employed in a well-known software company which outsources a team of developers (including me) to a large oil company. When negotiating, the name of client was kept in BIG COMMERCIAL SECRET, but working conditions were described by recruiter as acceptable: Well-formed processes, no legacy & modern stack, good compensation.

Currently there are 12 developers, manager, scrum master and devops in the team, 4 of developers came from our company. IMHO oil company's IT culture is at low level. IT is not primary business. Security service and bureaucracy disrupts daily and long-term progress. Widely accepted practices are not adopted here. I'll list some things that I find questionable in order of importance:

- Java developer spends as much time working with configs as with design/java code. Most of the time I'm correcting Openshift templates, builds, routes, etc for test/dev environments, admins do that for prod. Shouldn't this be done by devops? As far as I understand, java engineers build an app with placeholders for properties, devops takes care about properties being passed to JVM.

I haven't mastered openshift but even if i did (instead of mastering java frameworks), manual configuring will still consume much time.

- Every rollout takes a minute-two for changing configs (no matter what changed in code). Due to some reasons tens of redeployments are performed daily. There are many things to improve infrastructurally despite team exists more than a year and there is a devops attached.
- There are no testers. We perform manual testing, than business/IT colleagues who use our system try it, then it goes to prod env.
- Standups are used for detailed discussing of everything anyone wants, they often continue for 30-40 minutes despite most of conversation is irrelevant for majority
- Oil company's development infrastructure is available only via slow laggy RDP
- Any access requires a permit. Permissions are granted by security service after several days of pushing them; sometimes a fancifully-reasoned rejection comes.
- Workplace is neither comfortable nor upgradable

As a result, much more time is spent on slow procedures (devops/permits/useless communications/re-entering data because of internal portal failures) than designing/discussing solutions/coding.

Currently i have nice salary and i don't want to be a hopper. Also, I'm on evaluation period and soon we can be moved to an affiliated company, from which it will be harder to change project.

On the other side, I think this is not productive usage of my abilities, this is not interesting and not much useful for my specialization. My enthusiasm is low and it affects productivity. I did not know about such conditions when employing.

I'd lose 5-10% for a job with more programming. For me top alternative is asking employer for another project. But I need serious reasons for it, because this is an important contract for my employer and they don't want to damage relations with contractor (our team is kind of a pioneer group in this cooperation). What is your opinion? Are described practices bad enough to ask for switching?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> and after two weeks I left that place. This is important because switching often is undesired.

If you only spent two weeks at a job, you just leave it off your resume. That makes it irrelevant when being considered for employment. You will not look like a hopper.

> Java developer spends as much time working with configs as with design/java code. Most of the time I'm correcting Openshift templates, builds, routes, etc for test/dev environments, admins to that for prod. Shouldn't this be done by devops?

Most non-technicals have never heard of devops, so to them, they are one and the same job. Unless your company is technical, they often just do not exist. My company has plenty of developers but no devops.

> Every rollout takes a minute-two for changing configs (no matter what changed in code). There are many things to improve infrastructurally despite team exists more than a year and there is a devops attached.

I am not familiar with the platform, but surely this could be automated with an if statement or a Python script.

> There are no testers. We perform manual testing, than business/IT colleagues who use our system try it, then it goes to prod env.

Again, this is common, especially outside non tech firms. I am quite happy that I have two QAs. Nobody else I know has dedicated testers. Plenty of developers are against them existing and management is all too happy to cut costs, so they are getting less and less common.

> Standups are used for detailed discussing of everything anyone wants, they often continue for 30-40 minutes despite most of conversation is irrelevant for majority

Again, common. Happily not a problem I have currently, but this has happened at prior jobs.

> Oil company's development infrastructure is available only via slow laggy RDP.

This is common at non-tech firms.

> Any access requires a permit. Permissions are granted by security service after several days of pushing them; sometimes a fancifully-reasoned rejection comes.

Depending on what it is, this is actually good security practice. The response time is problematic however.

> Workplace is neither comfortable nor upgradable

Yeah, this is all the more reason to be prepared to leave. I spend 1/3 of my life in the chair coding for the company. It better be a decent chair.

> I think this is not productive usage of my abilities

**You really want to avoid letting your skills rot.** Losing your skills can trap you as a developer in a mediocre job. You have a mediocre job. It is not great, but it is also not exceptionally bad.

Your plan of switching projects has the flaw that consulting companies tend not to care about good practices and such. There is no point as they just bill it on to the company which hired them. It is easier to just use developers rather than dev ops as some non-technical at the oil company will wonder what it is and why they are paying for it. Absurd as it is, that is a true story.

You probably want to move to a legitimate tech company if you can.

Answer (score 12):

It's you.  You want to do all the fun stuff, and leave all the boring stuff to other people.  Meanwhile, your employer wants a small team of people who will just get on with whatever needs doing on the project now.

If you are working in any industry that involves secrecy (and that's quite a few when you bring in personal data protection rules), then you just have to put up with the bureaucracy that goes with it.  They want to keep the IT system, and the data on it, safe.

Comment: Wish I could upvote this more than once.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. But can you explain something for my understanding? As i get it, specialization is used in IT as much as in other industries, so testers test, programmers program and devops set up infrastructure for faster/safer/cheaper processes. In this case, my desire to leave "boring" stuff seems legit as such work is out of my professional scope. What is wrong in my insight?

Comment: Looks like nothing is wrong, just my specialization doesn't fit client's development model

Comment: To be fair to OP, there are companies where the "boring stuff" is not done by developers. So if that is what he wants, he should consider leaving.

Comment: @Juggernaut Often there simply is not enough work or money for dedicated devops or testers. If they add one devops to fiddle thumbs and reduce developers by one, you'd be even more upset. Instead they offer good compensation for qualified developers, who are assumed to be capable of handling wide range of responsibilities.

Comment: @Sopuli this is not the case, this client has tons of money but little expertise :) But thus exlains client's approach

Answer (score 1):

In my experience this is very much dependent on team size, *i.e.* scaling.

If you are in a large company (AND it translates to a large development team(s) ), then the things you mention are not unreasonable. Proper CI pipelines are then expected, so are departments specifically for testing. In this case **it's them**.

On the other hand, in a small company translating to a small software department, these things are absolutely typical. Manual testing by developers is typical, so is testing using non-designated departments. Not saying these things cannot exist in a small team, but they typically just don't. What you describe with regard to configs for deployment, as well as standups is also something not uncommon from my experience. Some of this is simply a matter of priorities. Testing teams and DevOps will, in the longterm, let you produce things faster, however first priority is to produce things at all. So obviously when you have 5 devs, you will not designate 2 to DevOps and 1 to testing. If this is what your team looks like, then I think your expectations may be unreasonable, so **it's you**.

---

Having said that, to me it sounds like the company you are contracted to does not put enough focus on software development. You said so yourself. In this case I do not expect a giant IT department, so these things are very typical.

Ultimately, you can add to changing this.

- You can suggest to pull team members from standups, if you think most of everyone's time is typically wasted. Don't try to revolutionize all processes at once, just try to come up with small suggestions. *Specifically such that business understands*.
- Possibly your team can designate testers upon deployment, if there are capacities that is. You can also suggest implementing test-driven development and framework usage to automate testing more as time goes on.
- Even if you are not on DevOps, since you are the one who is not satisfied with configuring prior to deployment, then automate this process. Setting up Jenkins is not too much to ask. I will also say, that 1-2min offset per deployment is barely worth mentioning, unless you deploy 50 times a day. Especially when compared to the offset created by the standups you mentioned.

---

Everything depends on what you want to do. If you want to work with small teams and develop their product, then these things are to be expected and absolutely common. If you prefer to work in an environment that offers all these processes you desire, which I find legitimate as well, then you will want to work for a large company that also has a large software department.

The smaller a team is, the less specialists it can afford. This is when Java developers set up configs and pipelines among their primary work. Personally I like it, you don't seem to. If so, look for a company suited to your wishes or change things step by step yourself.